# Forcing $ unescaped to error, not use math-mode

Tags: errors, tex-core

I am copying and pasting paragraphs into a LaTeX document from a report that contains frequent `$` signs. I would like any unescaped `$` to result in **an error** and perhaps a reminder to escape them. (Math mode could still be accessed through `\( ... \)`, though the absence of math mode is acceptable.)

My motivation behind this is that I am frequently missing things like:

> There were 150 accounts with a balance of between $1000 and $2000 in
>   this year.

which results in a short, valid math mode section that is easy to overlook.

I know I can use the text editor with a regex to solve this problem, but if I am giving the task to a LaTeX novice (who doesn't know regex), I would prefer they are reminded than trying to teach them regular expressions.

Comment: you could make an error or you could use `\catcode\`\$=12 ` so the `$` just work as normal punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding somewhere after `\begin{document}`

```
 \catcode`$=15 % for example - PS
```

gives what is expected in your question.